# Save Results from cursor.callproc in dict

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, mysql-connector-python

I'm trying to get some data from a `MySQL` database with a stored procedure and store it in a dict (as mentioned by blair [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursordict.html#docs-comments)):

```
    def createProduct(self):
    self.cursor.callproc('newProduct')

    result = []
    for recordset in self.cursor.stored_results():
        for row in recordset:
            result.append(dict(zip(recordset.column_names,row)))
            print(result)
```

The cursor is created with the option `dictionary=True`. The output for `print(result)` is:

> [{'manufacturers_id': 0, 'alarm_threshold': 10, 'users_id_tech': 0, 'name': 'item1', 
>   'entities_id': 0, 'notepad': None, 'locations_id': 0, 'groups_id_tech': 0,
>   'consumableitemtypes_id': 0, 'id': 1, 'comment': '', 'is_deleted': 0, 'ref': ''}]

I tried to access the value of the key `name` (which is `item1`) with this code:

```
print(result['name'])
```

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

and:

```
print(result(name))
```

> NameError: name 'name' is not defined

I thought the code from blair would create a dict whose values are accessible by keys (for example 'name')? Is this wrong or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the list of dictionary you posted, I think there is a problem with the way you are printing.

I think this

```
print(result['name'])
```

should become this

```
print(result[0]['name'])
```

since you are trying to acess a dictionary inside a list.
Hope it works.

Comment: Nie hint but results in a TypeError('dict' object is not callable). Is there a standard way of doing this ?

Comment: Are you acessing the dictionary with the square brackets as a told earlier?

Comment: like this `result[0]['name']` i am afraid you are trying to acess it something like this `result[0](name)` that's why you are getting the dict is not callable error. this error comes when you try to call a variable like a method. If not please do post how are you acessing the dictionary.

Comment: Damn, my fault. Had only square brackets around '0' and not around 'name'. Now it works. Thx!